# How to encrypt a message such that it cannot be decrypted before a certain time?

Tags: encryption

Suppose you have a message $m$ and you want to design a protocol that produces an encrypted message $c$ such that it cannot be decrypted before a certain time $t$ has passed from the encryption.

How would you realize this? What assumptions do you need?

I am just curious about it and I would like to discuss ideas (I have no clue if it is even possible).

Note that I am less interested in solutions that simply requires an amount of computation for decryption (assuming a certain amount of computing power) such that it takes a time $t$ to decrypt. Then, I suppose a kind of third-party/authority is required. What about a smart contract?

Look at it as a non-physical version of a timelock.

Comment: See the [first related question on the right](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/606).

Comment: From what it is explained [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/606/time-capsule-cryptography?rq=1), this is an issue but there are ways to mitigate it. Indeed, you do an assumption regarding the computing power of the receiver (of a single processor) of the message and, among other properties, you design a puzzle whose best algorithm to solve it is intrinsically sequential (parallel computing does not help).