# How can we construct stationary and non-stationary time locks?

Tags: proof-of-work, timestamping, timed-release

Time locks enables us to encrypt data for a period of time, up to a certain deadline, such that even a computationally powerful adversary is not able to learn any substantial information about the data before the deadline. Time locks received a lot of attention ever since blockchain smart contracts have started using them for various decentralized financial use cases such as flash loans and blockchain interoperability focused bridge smart contracts. I am exploring the possibility of using different types of time locks for use cases such as algorithmic stable coins which requires different types of time locks. What are the possible cryptographic schemes and approaches to construct stationary, linear and non-linear time-locks.

Comment: It's at least disputable that _"Time locks enables us to encrypt data for a period of time, up to a certain deadline, such that even a computationally powerful adversary is not able to learn any substantial information about the data before the deadline."_ That's the subject of a  highly voted [question  here on crypto-SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/606/555). As a crypto practitioner, my [take at it](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1033/555) is that it's not practical, much like an alarm clock that you program for 8 hours of sleep but might ring in 3 or 20 hours is not practical.

Comment: As to _"various decentralized financial use cases such as flash loans and blockchain interoperability focused bridge smart contracts"_, that's off-topic. It's pretty much what https://web3isgoinggreat.com/ is about, and I get a weekly dose of that.